# Counting existing records in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple php/mysql script that stores in mysql database id, link, and date fields. It stores various links and some of them appear several times. I would like to count the number of times each link was accessed. I was thinking of adding new field counter and updating it every time new record is inserted, but this needs to check if the link already exists and update counter when necessary.

This means I would have to:
1. Search the entire table to look if the link already inserted.
2. If no - insert it and set counter to value of 1.
3. If yes - find the correct record and update its counter by 1.

I would like to have something like:
1. www.link1.com 11:20
2. www.link2.com 11:30
3. www.link1.com 11:40

www.link1.com counter: 2 times
www.link2.com counter: 1 time

I am wondering what is the best way to do that? Should I rather create a new table that stores the counter for each link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you need to track. Do you only need to track total number of visits? If so, add a column to your table. You don't need to check wheter the link exists if you want to update the counter this way.

If you need to track who visisted when etc, create a new table with a foreign key and neccesary columns to your table. With this, you need to have the id of your link, but when you update the number of visits, you should already have it.

Comment: I need to track the total numbers of visits for each link so  I can print a list of links with corresponding values (how many times accessed). I think that just adding the column will not solve the problem - in this case I would have a list of links with counters set to value 1.

Comment: Adding a column that contains number of visits for each link will definitely solve your problem. When you need to update the counter for a link, just issue a query like `UPDATE links SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE id = <id>`. When you print your list, just select counter and display it.

Comment: Well, I got your point, but this is not a table of links but a table of visits. That's what makes it harder. In your case I would end up with a list of links with counters and a date of the last access. I would like to have a list of visits (kind of log), but also count the number each link was accessed (and when).

Comment: Alright. Can't you just count the number of time a given link exists in your database? Like, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visits WHERE link = <link>`. A solution to your problem of update when exists / insert when not exists, is to use `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY`. More info here, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html.

Answer (score 0):

creating a new field and incrementing it is probably the simplest approach and should be easy to do.

If your site has users logging in, then you might want to create a table like `users_links` and store a record each time a user clicks a link, this way you can get the number of clicks, as well as more useful things like distinct users clicking, a history of what each user clicks on, correlations between link popularity and more!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I didn't understand, but if you have this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `link` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

And these data:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`link`, `id`) VALUES
(1, 'link1'),
(2, 'link2'),
(3, 'link1'),
(4, 'link2'),
(5, 'link1'),
(6, 'link1'),
(7, 'link3');
```

If I want to see how many occurrences of each link, I can use the `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY` from MySQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(link), link FROM `test` WHERE 1 GROUP BY link
```

And I get:

```
4 link1
2 link2
1 link3
```

Is it this you are looking for?